# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') in NodeJs using MongoDB and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my userModel.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const emailValidator = require('email-validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        validate:function(){
            return emailValidator.validate(this.email);
        }
    },
    password:String,
    confirmPass:{
        type:String,
        validate:function(){
            return this.password == this.confirmPass;
        }
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        enum:['user','admin'],
        default:'user'
    },
    profilepic:{
        type:String,
        default:'img/default.jpeg'
    }
});



const userModel = new mongoose.model('userModel',userSchema);
console.log(userModel);

module.exports = userModel;
```

I am trying to save a user data on mongoDb using

```
const {userModel} =  require('../models/userModel');


const userSignup = async (req,res)=>{
    try{

        const data = await userModel.create(req.body);
        if(data){
            res.json({message:"Data Added", data:data});
        }
        else{
            res.json({message:"Something went wrong!"});
        }
        

    }catch(err){
        res.json({message:"Data not added", error:err.message});
    }
    
}
```

when I hit the api 'localhost:3000/user/signup'
It says :

{
"message": "Data not added",
"error": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')"
}

Please tell me how to get rid of this.

Comment: Got the answer after going through the code again and again, wrongly imported my `userModel` , use simply `const userModel =  require('../models/userModel');` instead of `const {userModel} =  require('../models/userModel');`.